# Gitlab: semi-automatically installing hook scripts by default in a new repo

Tags: git, gitlab

In summary, my question is: how can I ensure that all newly created repositories in gitlab have a default initial commit which includes some files of my choosing (hook scripts)?

Some background: My company is switching to using git and gitlab (away from svn - hooray!) for internal development.

When a user creates a new repo in gitlab, I want that new repo to be autopopulated with some files of my choosing.  Those files will be hook scripts and a script to install them.  That way, when the user clones the repo they just created it will already have hook scripts in it (which will enforce company commit message policy), which they can install.

Now I know that gitlab allows you to specify a url to a cgi script which will be called (among other times) when a new repo is created.  My idea is to have a "skeleton" repository somewhere with the appropriate initial commit in it, and make this cgi script do a push from that repository into the newly minted repo.

The problem with this plan is one of permissions: this cgi script will need to be run as a user who has an ssh key set up which has commit access on the new repository - on EVERY new repository by DEFAULT.

Is there a way to ensure that every newly created repository is write-accessible by a particular user in gitlab?

Is there another way to ensure that every newly created repo gets a specified initial commit?

Is there a better way to ensure distribution of these hook scripts that I haven't thought of?

Comment: You start out talking about cloned repositories then switch to talking about blank repositories that are brand new with nothing in them.  Which are you asking about? Both?

Comment: Gitlab creates new, blank repositories.  I want a hook script to automatically put some default files in each new repository when it is created.  I have edited the post to (hopefully) clarify this point.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem before and I solved it by creating a dedicated hooks repository everyone can access. After creating a new repository users were supposed to run a script in this hooks repo. This script simply created a symbolic link from the new repo's .git/hooks directory to the hooks repo, where all hooks are stored. This way, users can also update all of their hooks by simply pulling a new version of the hooks repo. Here is the related question: [Gitolite: print message after git clone finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681139/gitolite-print-message-after-git-clone-finished)

Only problem with this approach: users need to run the hook script every time they create a new repo.

Comment: You could change the `init.templatedir` setting so that it returns a directory where would store a symlink to your hooks directory.